# Sequelize hasMany, belongsTo, or both?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I want to properly setup one-to-one or one-to-many relationship with sequelize and as a matter of fact it all seems to be working just fine if i use either one of `hasOne`/ `hasMany` or `belongsTo` in my model definition. 
For example the following associations do create the `userId` field on their Targets:

```
    User.hasMany(Email, {
        as: 'emails',
        foreignKey: 'userId',
    })

    User.hasOne(Profile, {
        as: 'profile',
        foreignKey: 'userId',
    })
```

But almost everywhere in official docs i see something like:

```
   Projects.hasMany(Tasks);
   Tasks.belongsTo(Projects);
```

i.e. `hasMany` AND `belongsTo` are being used together.

Is this really required or it is enough to use just one of them? Any further explanation would be really valuable. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using `belongsTo` defines the ownership of the associated models. To explain this in more detail I will refer to the example cited from the tutorials

```
Project.hasMany(Task);
Task.belongsTo(Project);
```

Assume that you are no longer interested in the tasks of a deleted project. In that case you would have to delete the tasks manually, had you not defined the `belongsTo` association. `belongsTo` establishes an ownership of projects over it's tasks and the database will automatically delete the tasks belonging to the deleted project as well. This is called `cascading delete` and can chain over multiple tables.

If you run the following code snippet

```
const Project = sequelize.define('project', {
    name: Sequelize.STRING
});
const Task =  sequelize.define('task', {
    name: Sequelize.STRING
});
Project.hasMany(Task);
Task.belongsTo(Project);
```

in a sequelize script and watch the output

```
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `projects`;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `projects` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `name` VARCHAR(255), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL);
Executing (default): PRAGMA INDEX_LIST(`projects`)
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tasks`;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tasks` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `name` VARCHAR(255), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `projectId` INTEGER REFERENCES `projects` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

you will notice the cascading behaviour being set in the creation of the tasks table.

So much said, the final answer is: it depends. The use of `belongsTo` can come very handy or will be fatal if you would rather keep the tasks of the deleted project. Only use `belongsTo` if it makes sense in the context of your application.

Comment: afaik, it is also possible to get the cascade effect with hasOne/Many, i.e something like `Project.hasMany(Task, {onDelete: 'cascade'})` should do the job