# Node.js Sequelize model where one field is an array of objects

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I'm working on adding a shopping cart to my Node web app and I need to create a model for each purchase. A purchase should have a "contents" field that lists the items that the user purchased. I envision the contents as being of the form

```
contents: [{
    "id": id of product being purchased,
    "quantity": number of product being purchased
}]
```

I'm having trouble creating a model for this. Should I use Array or Enum? Can I map that id field to the product id in a different table?

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45389747/sequelize-hasmany-belongsto-or-both

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the data model described below. It will give you some clarity- 
[image: Sample ERD for e-commerce website]

If you are convinced with the data model described above then you can go ahead and create respective models and associations in Sequelize.